# how to send object one controller to another controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

can you please tell me how to send object one controller to another controller in angular ?I am able to do by sending in parameter .is there any other way to send object in another controller ?

I do like this 
on **button** click I do like this .data is object.user id is string.

```
 $location.path('/navigation/'+JSON.stringify(data)+"/"+$scope.userId);
```

**in configuration**

```
when('/navigation/:userDetail/:voterID',{
            templateUrl: 'partial/userdetail.html',
            controller: 'userdetail'
        })
```

**I retrieve like that**

```
console.log(JSON.parse($routeParams.userDetail));
```

is there any another way to send object in another view with out using local storage

```
$scope.checkPerson=function(){
    $scope.loading=true;
    $http.post('http://192.168.11.218:8082/onlinevote/rss/checkUserDetail',  {
        "voterID":$scope.userId,
        "name":$scope.userName,
        "fatherName":$scope.fatherName,
        "territory":$scope.territory,
        "dOB":$scope.dOB
    }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
            $scope.loading=false;
            $scope.loading=false;
            if(data.msg!="Already Vote with this id!")
            $location.path('/navigation/'+JSON.stringify(data)+"/"+$scope.userId)
            alert(data.msg)
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            alert('error')
            $scope.loading=false;
        });
}
```

how to share with service ?
is there any one idea ?

Comment: Consider using a Service. Angular Services are ideal for sharing data between controllers in an application.

Comment: how do you have any idea...please take static data...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Let me elaborate on what I was saying. The idea of Services is that they can be required in each controller. So you can send data to a Service in one controller. That information then remains in the service throughout the state of the application. Then, you can inject that service into another controller and retrieve its data.

Comment: I will explain .please first check update.Actually on click button i call webservice .and get the response.that response i need to send another controller .now I am sending like parameter

Comment: is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Angular services are singletons. For this reason, they are the [recommended way to share information between app components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

The scope [$emit, $broadcast and $on methods](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) provide an event system that can pass data between parent and child scopes. It is a more advanced feature than services.

Answer (score 0):

It's easily achievable using services: Running example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DeIIBNNedyTFEcwAH3b8?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="Ctr1">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Data.LastName">
  <br>First Name in Ctr1 : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
  <br>Last Name in Ctr1: <strong>{{Data.LastName}}</strong>
</div>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="Ctr2">
  <br>First Name shared in Ctr2 : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
  <br>Last Name shared in Ctr2: <strong>{{Data.LastName}}</strong>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return { };
});

myApp.controller('Ctr1', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('Ctr2', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```